# NSTextFieldCell with Multiple Lines

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsoutlineview, nscell, nstextfieldcell

I need to show an NSTextFieldCell with multiple lines with different format on each line.

Something like this:

Line 1: **Title**
Line 2: *Description*

I subclassed NSTextFieldCell but I don't know how to go on with it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First off, you don't *have* to subclass `NSTextFieldCell` to achieve this, since, as a subclass of `NSCell`, `NSTextFieldCell` inherits `-setAttributedStringValue:`. The string you provided can be represented as a `NSAttributedString`. The following code illustrates how you could achieve the desired text with an ordinary `NSTextField`.

MDAppController.h:

```
@interface MDAppController : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
    IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
    IBOutlet NSTextField *textField;
}

@end
```

MDAppController.m:

```
@implementation MDAppController

static NSDictionary *regularAttributes = nil;
static NSDictionary *boldAttributes = nil;
static NSDictionary *italicAttributes = nil;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

    if (regularAttributes == nil) {
        regularAttributes = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        [NSFont systemFontOfSize:[NSFont systemFontSize]],NSFontAttributeName,
                       nil] retain];

        boldAttributes = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        [NSFont boldSystemFontOfSize:[NSFont systemFontSize]],NSFontAttributeName,
                  nil] retain];

        NSFont *regFont = [NSFont userFontOfSize:[NSFont systemFontSize]];
        NSFontManager *fontManager = [NSFontManager sharedFontManager];
        NSFont *oblique = [fontManager convertFont:regFont
                                       toHaveTrait:NSItalicFontMask];
        italicAttributes = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
              oblique,NSFontAttributeName, nil] retain];
    }


    NSString *string = @"Line 1: Title\nLine 2: Description";
    NSMutableAttributedString *rString =
    [[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string] autorelease];

    [rString addAttributes:regularAttributes
                     range:[string rangeOfString:@"Line 1: "]];

    [rString addAttributes:regularAttributes
                     range:[string rangeOfString:@"Line 2: "]];
    [rString addAttributes:boldAttributes
                     range:[string rangeOfString:@"Title"]];

    [rString addAttributes:italicAttributes
                     range:[string rangeOfString:@"Description"]];

    [textField setAttributedStringValue:rString];
}
@end
```

This results in the following:

[image]

Now, depending on how you intend for this text to be used, you could implement the design in several different ways. You may want to look into whether an `NSTextView` might work for you rather than an `NSTextField`...

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with using an [NSTextView](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)?