# Create a complex custom nstextfieldcell

Tags: objective-c, nstableview, nstextfieldcell

I'm trying to create a custom `NSTextFieldCell` for a `NSTableView`. I want to do something like the email listing provided by Mail (example below).

I found some references [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6552682/nstextfieldcell-with-multiple-lines) and [here](http://juliuspaintings.co.uk/cgi-bin/paint_css/animatedPaint/070-NSTableView-ImageAndTextCell.pl), but I'm not able to evolve.

I think that it's not as simple as a multiline text. I think the cell should have predefined places, like the timestamp on the upper right corner, the attchment icon, etc... This "placeholders" should be always at the same place, regardless the text size. I'm thinking about embeeded objects.

Please, could you help me? An example or sample code is very welcome.

EDIT: I'm looking for a MAC OS X Lion (10.7.x) solution.

[image: Cell example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Monolo comment, I googled view-based table view. I found [this excellent tutorial](http://gentlebytes.com/2011/08/view-based-table-views-in-lion-part-1-of-2/) and followed it and I succeeded.

I also found this [OS X Developer Library document](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/ViewBasedTables/ViewBasedTables.html) regarding view-based programming guide. Very good too.

Comment: both links seem broken